# What is the filename of my view?

Tags: vim, view

I am using:

```
au BufWinLeave ?* mkview 1
au BufWinLeave ?* silent loadview 1
```

This works to save my folds, but I'm not sure where they're being saved to. I would like to be able to commit the folds using bzr so that my team will be able to utilize them. Where is the view file located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share folds the best choice is using foldmarkers:

```
#{{{1 First-level fold name
…
#{{{2 Second-level fold name
…
#}}}2 End of second-level fold
…
#{{{1 Next first-level fold name
…
```

I prefer doing the different thing though:

```
#▶1 First-level fold
…
#▲1 End of first-level fold
# vim: fmr=▶,▲
```

. But if you still want to use manual folds here is the doc:

> `:h :mkview`
>
> ```
> :mkvie[w][!] [file]   Write a Vim script that restores the contents of the
>             current window.
>             When [!] is included an existing file is overwritten.
>             When [file] is omitted or is a number from 1 to 9, a
>             name is generated and 'viewdir' prepended.  When the
>             last directory name in 'viewdir' does not exist, this
>             directory is created.
> ```
>
> `:h 'viewdir'`, normally jumped to using `<C-]>` when cursor is on `'viewdir'` in the previous help text.
>
> ```
> 'viewdir' 'vdir'  string  (default for Amiga, MS-DOS, OS/2 and Win32:
>                              "$VIM/vimfiles/view",
>                  for Unix: "~/.vim/view",
>                  for Macintosh: "$VIM:vimfiles:view"
>                  for VMS: "sys$login:vimfiles/view"
>                  for RiscOS: "Choices:vimfiles/view")
> ```

It would be better if you read the docs for yourself, vim has good documentation.